# Mysql update if array key from array value

Tags: php, mysql

I can't find a simple solution for this.

I have an array where keys are old IDs and values are new IDs :

```
[
 12 => 42,
 13 => 43,
 ... => ...
]
```

My rows has 2 ID fields (not primary, it stores the ID of the user who has a definite role)

I need to update a field with the array value if it's actual value is the array key.

If my row is :

```
role_1_id : 12
role_2_id : 13
```

It must be updated to

```
role_1_id : 42
role_2_id : 43
```

Is there a way to do it easily with only SQL ?

Edit : 
What i'm looking for could be compared to PHP function str_replace, when you give arrays as arguments :

```
str_replace([12, 13], [42, 43], $row);
```

But full SQL...

Comment: so you want to update the array key to its respective value??  like `2=>5` to `5=>5` ??

Comment: Please post what you have tried already and does not work.

Comment: @KavinSmk nope, this is the row that must be updated, if a key is detected, it must be replaced by corresponding value

Comment: @RiggsFolly My current approach is similar to Thegreenkey's answer. But i feel like there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to iterate over the array, executing the following SQL for each element:

```sql
UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = :newValue WHERE myColumn = :oldValue
```

So, for example, using PDO:

```php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.DBNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

$cmd = $pdo->prepare('
  UPDATE myTable
  SET    myColumn = :newValue
  WHERE  myColumn = :oldValue
');

$cmd->bindParam(':oldValue', $old, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cmd->bindParam(':newValue', $new, PDO::PARAM_INT);

foreach ($array as $old => $new) $cmd->execute();
```

You can, of course, wrap those operations within a database transaction if you want to ensure that they are atomic.  Alternatively, you could express the entire operation as a single update:

```sql
UPDATE myTable
SET    myColumn = CASE myColumn
         WHEN :oldValue1 THEN :newValue1
         WHEN :oldValue2 THEN :newValue2
         -- etc
       END
WHERE  myColumn IN (:oldValue1, :oldValue2, ...)
```

I'll leave you to work out for yourself how such SQL can be constructed in PHP.

Comment: I like the single update way. Is there any risks of doing that if the array is really big ?

Comment: @FC': Both the client and server have a maximum packet size, and your SQL must fit within such a packet—see [Packet Too Large](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/packet-too-large.html) for more information.  Other than that, you're just creating unnecessary complexity for yourself (in having to build such SQL in the first place, and then have MySQL parse it in the second place).  There's really very little (to no) reason that one would prefer that approach over the first that I have shown.

Comment: @FC': Okay, I take that back.  If `myColumn` is not indexed, then each `UPDATE` operation will require a full table scan—thus if the table is sufficiently large, it may be more performant to use the second form of query (which can be done with only one pass of the table) rather than the first (once per update).  However, if that has become a material performance concern, then one probably ought to consider indexing `myColumn` and eliminating the table scans altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This almost seems too simple

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    //Update database where $key is the old id and $value the new id
}
```

Edit:
Okay... seeing that you edited your question to ask for an 'only SQL solution' this answer is no longer the best approach..

Comment: Yes, thanks for trying but if my array contains thousands of values I don"t want to make 1000 queries just to update 2 values

Comment: Yeah, I thought the values in the arrays are only existing if the data has changed and I don't have an approach to do this only on sql basis.